# How can I create delay between audioRecord and audioTrack

Tags: java, android

I want to create echo like Delayed Auditory Feedback(DAF). I tried to use sleep or change sample rate but it didn't help me.
It is code from [here](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/android-audio-demo-audiotrack.html)

```
private void init() 
{
    int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min);

    int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(9000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, 9000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
}

private void recordAndPlay()
{
    short[] lin = new short[1024];
    int num = 0;
    am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    record.startRecording();
    track.play();
    while (true) {
        num = record.read(lin, 0, 1024);
        track.write(lin, 0, num);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use Handler and put **recordAndPlay()** method in run() method

Comment: Can you give me example, please ?

Comment: `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() { recordAndPlay();
            }
        }, 5000);`

Comment: Could you explain me why you choose to use with handler instead of thread ?

Comment: This solution creates delay only on startup application @ArpitPrajapati

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[hander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012993/how-can-i-create-delay-between-audiorecord-and-audiotrack/46013010#46013010)** for delay between audioRecord and audioTrack

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               // after three seconds this code will execute
               // do your work here

              recordAndPlay();
            }
        }, 3000);// time in milliseconds 3000 means 3 seconds( 1000 = 1 second)
```

**import this class** `import android.os.Handler;`

Comment: which task you want to delay

Comment: record.startRecording(); sleep(60);
  track.play();

Comment: But it also creates delay on record. I want to create only on play

Comment: first record than play

Comment: @Alex just call your recordAndPlay() method like check updated ans

Comment: Could you explain me why you choose to use with handler instead of thread ?

Comment: This solution creates delay only on startup application @Nilesh Rathod

Answer (score 0):

try to replace your **recordAndPlay()** method with below code

```
private void recordAndPlay() {
    short[] lin = new short[1024];
    int num = 0;
    am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    record.startRecording();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            track.play();
        }
    }, 5000);
    while (true) {
        num = record.read(lin, 0, 1024);
        track.write(lin, 0, num);
    }
}
```